# Delete larger dataset with 10 Million records from HPE mapR table

Tags: mapr

I am trying to delete some larger dataset from HPE mapR table . This is taking more time when we do with mapR dbshell since it is deleting documents one by one . Is there anyway for the batch processing on deleting ?